# How do I enable rating for SharePoint 2016 Discussion board and not send out an email notification?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, discussion-board, outgoing-email

I have a SharePoint 2016 site with a Discussion Board.  We want to enable the Like ration option, but not send an email notification to the person who posted the topic.

Here are the 2 scenarios I see right now.

1. Allow items in this list to be rated? = **No**
   There is no Like button under the discussion topic, or replies.
   When a user replies to the original post, there are no email notifications sent to the person who posted the topic.
2. Allow items in this list to be rated? = **Yes** > **Like**
   There is aLike button under the discussion topic, or replies.
   When a user replies to the original post, an email notifications sent to the person who posted the topic.
   The email being sent appears to be based the default Email Notification settings in the user's MySite.

What we want is to:

- Enable the **Like** button
- Do NOT send the email notification to the person who posted the topic.

Any ideas how to configure the Discussion Board to fit our needs?

Answer (score 0):

The Email notification cannot be turned off in the Discussion Board list.

This can only be modified in the user’s **personal email settings** via `My Site > Edit profile > Newsfeed Settings` and uncheck **Someone replied to my community discussion post** under Email Notifications.

[image]